# i have a question with a pong game for school c#

Tags: c#

for school i need to make a pong game
its nearly finished but i want to add a messagebox that says ''good job'' after i destroyed all the blocks
but i tried to put it in my timer, and when i started the game thousands of messagebox shows up and i cant move my paddle.

here is my code for the timer

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //afstand bal van de top
        picBall.Top += vSpeed;
        //afstand bal van links
        picBall.Left += hSpeed;

        //zorgt dat die niet door bottom gaat
        if (picBall.Bottom > this.ClientSize.Height)
        {
            vSpeed = -vSpeed;

        }
        //zorgt dat die niet door top gaat
        if (picBall.Top < 0)
        {
            vSpeed = -vSpeed;
        }
        //zorgt dat die niet door right gaat
        if (picBall.Right > this.ClientSize.Width)
        {
            hSpeed = -hSpeed;
        }
        //zorgt dat die niet door left gaat
        if (picBall.Left < 0)
        {
            hSpeed = -hSpeed;
        }

        //wanneer de bal de paddle raakt
        if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picPaddle.Bounds) == true)
        {
            vSpeed = -vSpeed;
        }

        //als de bal de grond raakt verlies je en gaat de form dicht
        if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picGrond.Bounds) == true)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("you lose!");
            this.Close();
        }


        //DIT ZORGT DAT ALLE BLOKKEN WEG GAAN
        //DIT ZORGT DAT ALLE BLOKKEN WEG GAAN
        //DIT ZORGT DAT ALLE BLOKKEN WEG GAAN

        //zorgt dat de bal de blokken raakt en niet door de blokken heen ga
        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds) && pictureBox1.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;

                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) && pictureBox2.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox3.Bounds) && pictureBox3.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox3.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox4.Bounds) && pictureBox4.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox4.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox5.Bounds) && pictureBox5.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox5.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox6.Bounds) && pictureBox6.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox6.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox7.Bounds) && pictureBox7.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox7.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox8.Bounds) && pictureBox8.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox8.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox9.Bounds) && pictureBox9.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox9.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox10.Bounds) && pictureBox10.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox10.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }


        //PICTUREBOX 11 : 3X RAKEN DAT DIE WEG GAAT EN 3X KLEUR VERANDERING
        //for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        //{
            //for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            //{   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                //  if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox11.Bounds) && pictureBox11.Visible == true)

                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox11.Bounds) && HitCount ==3)
                {
                    pictureBox11.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                    HitCount--;
                }

                else if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox11.Bounds) && HitCount == 2)
                {
                    pictureBox11.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                    HitCount--;
                }
                else if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox11.Bounds) && HitCount == 1)
                {
                    pictureBox11.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                    HitCount--;
                }
                 else if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox11.Bounds) && HitCount == 0 && pictureBox11.Visible == true)
                 {
                pictureBox11.Visible = false;
                 vSpeed = -vSpeed;

                 }





        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox12.Bounds) && pictureBox12.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox12.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox13.Bounds) && pictureBox13.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox13.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox14.Bounds) && pictureBox14.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox14.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {   //zorgt dat de bal de blokken weg laat verdwijnen en als de blok die weg is weg is dan doet die er niks meer mee
                if (picBall.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox15.Bounds) && pictureBox15.Visible == true)
                {
                    pictureBox15.Visible = false;
                    vSpeed = -vSpeed;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

in my game i have 15 bricks to destroy with the ball and as you can see i made 14 same codes for each brick. and 1 brick needs 3 times to hit to be destroyed. but that works perfectly

my question is where to put the messagebox if you destroyed all the bricks?

i tried to do it end the end of the code but it doesnt work
sorry for my english and thanks for your help

Comment: Just a comment because I am not an expert in games logic, but, when you create the wall put all your pictureBoxX in an array. At the end of the timer click event check of all pictureBox have Visible=false. If yes display your win message

Comment: If you want people to read your code, please translate the comments to english. Anders kunnen alleen nederlanders en belgen het lezen :D

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new method that gets called when a brick gets hit by the ping pong ball. The method would check each brick’s state (if it’s destroyed) and if all bricks are destroyed then display the message. This would not be displayed again as you won’t hit a brick if all are destroyed.